# Are score sheet booklets allowed to be in use?

Tags: rules, fide, scoresheet

Is it allowed to use a score sheet booklet for notations (with a recording of previous games), as opposed to a single "stand alone" sheet?

Reasons for not allowing this may, of course, be due to the possibility of cheating, for example, by having opening line reminders on previous pages and making use of them during the game. On the other hand, one may also have such notes in one's pocket, and I don't believe there's a prohibition against this, only against the usage thereof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to an [annotated version](https://www.norfolkchess.org/PDF/Laws_of_Chess_2017.pdf) of the FIDE rules (*FIDE Laws of Chess 2017*, by the Chess Arbiters' Association), it's banned in some tournaments, which presumably means it's not banned in *all* tournaments.  The relevant annotation (the bottom of p.23) says:

> Article 11.3.1 has resulted in some tournaments banning the use of scorebooks.  Where these are allowed arbiters should ensure that players do not refer to earlier games.

I've never played in a FIDE tournament, but I've played in USCF tournaments. The relevant USCF rules are similar to the FIDE rules. A tournament can prohibit using scorebooks, but in my (amateur) experience they don't; probably many tournament directors are happy to not have to provide as many scoresheets.

USCF rule 15A (similar to FIDE rule 8.1.1) states that you are to record your moves "on the scoresheet prescribed for the competition".  This is clear, but it's also only relevant if the competition prescribes a scoresheet.

USCF rule 20B (simiar to FIDE rule 11.3.1) states you are forbidden to "make use of" notes or recorded matter - it doesn't prohibit having them in a place where you can't see them. Generally a notation booklet will be open in such a way that you only have the current game visible, and not any previous games. Browsing notes on previous pages would of course be cheating, but it would also be fairly obvious to your opponent and any bystanders.  The only legitimate reason to flip a page after the game has started is if you get to move 50 or so, and by that time any opening notes would be rather useless.

While USCF rule 15G (similar to FIDE rule 8.3) does state that the scoresheets are property of the sponsoring organization, I've never had a tournament ask me to rip a page out. I get the feeling that this rule is mostly there so a player can't refuse to show it during a dispute, and it allows the arbiter/TD to insist that the opponent be able to use it to fill in his own sheet.

And finally, the USCF sells these score books on their website, calling them "A must for the 'organized' tournament player!". Presumably, they would not do so if it was ordinarily illegal to actually use them for their intended purpose.

Comment: I see this commentary is from an association of UK arbiters. I suppose other arbiters and other organizations might have different interpretations, but the implication of this interpretation is quite clear (that a score sheet booklet is permitted unless explicitly banned), and it seems safe to infer from that, that this matter is at least open to interpretation, certainly so as the FIDE rules do not imply a prohibition of the usage of such a booklet, but only of usage of notes.

Comment: Germany: Banned since already ages. (1980 latest) Of course you can copy your games to a scorebook afterwards, and I always did, but nowadays you would copy directly to electronic format...given that some of your games will be available in that format anyway due to the tournament directors providing the service.

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking the answer is "No". The reason being this section of the FIDE Laws of Chess -

> 11.3.1 During play the players are forbidden to use any notes, sources of information or advice, or analyse any game on another chessboard.

In practice it will depend on the competition. If it is your local chess league or internal club competition where everybody knows everybody then probably no problem. However if it is a large congress then if the arbiter sees you doing this or your opponent does and complains to the arbiter then you will be asked to put the scorebook away and use the provided scoresheet.

There is not normally a punishment for a first offence. Repeated offences against this rule can lead to defaulting the game as happened to Wesley So when he repeatedly looked at notes he had written to himself not with chess moves but inspirational advice.

Note also Article 8.3

> 8.3 The scoresheets are the property of the organiser of the competition.

For serious FIDE rated tournaments the scoresheets will be collected each round, the games entered on a computer and the PGNs published. For norm events these PGNs must be sent to FIDE. For these events your scorebook is not acceptable and you will be asked to use the scoresheet provided.

Comment: Well, the question was not about actual usage of such notes, of course. Rather, the question was if the mere existence of score sheets from previous games within said booklet means that the booklet is not allowed.

Comment: Said booklet is not allowed to be used according to the rules. Period.

Comment: I take it this should be taken as your personal opinion then, as the quotations given above didn't really relate to the usage of the booklet (11.3,1 relates to usage of notes & 8.3 relates to proprietary issues of score sheets handed out at the tournament).

Comment: No. This is what I've been taught as part of my qualification as a FIDE Arbiter. The other games in your scorebook are notes. If your scorebook is open for you to record your current game that is taken as evidence that you are using your scorebook and its notes. It is not allowed.

Comment: @BrianTowers If 11.3.1 was the reason, then it would seem you could use an empty scorebook (but you couldn't use it for a second game, which defeats the entire purpose.)  And if 8.3 was the reason, you'd simply have to tear the page out if they requested it. But perhaps clearer is article 8.1, which states that you are to record your moves "on the scoresheet prescribed for the competition".

Answer (score 2):

Some tournaments (usually the higher level ones), provide score sheets that you have to hand in after the game. They use them to publish the games on their website, to TWIC, and so on. They are often carbon paper so you get a copy to keep as well.

In my experience, such tournaments make using those sheets mandatory, so alternatives aren't allowed. And tournaments where you don't have to hand in the sheet don't care what your record your game on.